# I want to get that output spoken by my voice assistant. But it is showing me the error

Tags: python, python-3.x

This program is working perfectly but I want to implement it in my voice assistant program so whatever output it is getting printed. I want to get that output spoken by my voice assistant. But it is showing me the error. You can see it in this image. [https://i.postimg.cc/fyrD4Tjb/image.png]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
            
elif 'weather' in query:
                city = query

                url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + "weather" + city
                html = requests.get(url).content

                soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
                temp = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd'}).text
                str = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'BNeawe tAd8D AP7Wnd'}).text

                data = str.split('\n')
                info = data[1]
                listdiv = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd'})
                strd = listdiv[5].text
                pos = strd.find('Wind')
                other_data = strd[pos:]

                print('The Weather In', city, 'is', info, 'And The Temperature In', city, 'is', temp, 'and', other_data)
                speak('The Weather In', city, 'is', info, 'And The Temperature In', city, 'is', temp, 'and', other_data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that I did is I put the text to speak in an `fstring` and it worked for me.

```
print('The Weather In', city, 'is', info, 'And The Temperature In', city, 'is', temp, 'and', other_data)
speak(f"'The Weather In' {city} 'is' {info} 'And The Temperature In' {city} 'is' {temp} 'and' {other_data}")
```

This worked for me and my voice spoke the text.
Output (although i cannot post voice here)

```
it is 15:41 hours now...
Listening...
Recognizing...
weather in Oslo
The Weather In weather in oslo is Cloudy And The Temperature In weather in oslo is 21°C and .  # this is the text that is spoken out
```

If this solution does not work for you, then you may need to provide your code for TTS to see how you have written and what could be done.
I used `pyttsx3` and python's `speech recognition` libraries

Also, my output has 'the weather in Weather in oslo...' because I have only one way keyword, i.e., if there is weather in my speech, the code would recognize it and execute the block. Now, you have passed as `city = query` which means, my query will have 'Weather in Olso', and the static text also has the same text 'The Weather In', and hence the reps. I had a solution to this also where I split the query and use the last item as city name, but since you haven't showed your code regarding this, I assume you could figure out based on your style of coding.